# Javascript: Canvas drawing - storing mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, array, canvas

I have a small JS application that allows a user, after clicking on a canvas, to draw a picture.

Once the user clicks the mouse, the user is allowed to drag the mouse wherever they want within the canvas and a line will be drawn from where they started moving the mouse to where the mouse stopped.

Only by clicking again will the drawing cease.

The code I have for this is below, and one concern of mine is how I'm storing the coordinates of the mouse's position each time it moves.

```
var draw = false;
var coords = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    coords = [];
    draw = !draw;
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (draw) {
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var coord = { 'x': event.x - this.offsetLeft, 'y': event.y - thisoffsetTop };
        coords.push(coord);
        var max = coords.length - 1;
        if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {
            var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
            context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

I have a feeling that I could be storing the coordinates more efficiently, rather than just add them to an ever-increasing `Array`. Is this the right approach, or is there a more efficient way of handling this sort of storage?

Comment: Do you need the coordinates later for something, like storing them on a server? With the code as-is, you do not need to store all coordinates at all: only the previous one in order to draw the line.

Comment: No, I only need the current pair of coordinates and the previous pair. That was my idea, but I'm unsure of how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I want to give you a thumbs up for a clear description of your code. It really helps with reading.

<sup><sub>And another before-we-begin thing: you've got a missing `.` in your longest line of the code, near the end: `-  thisoffsetTop };`.</sub></sup>

---

## Main changes

Indeed, as you do not need to store all the coordinates, it's not efficient to save them all.
To draw a line between the current and previous point, all you need are those two points.
So, the first thing we can do with the code is to refactor that away: **use `prevCoord` instead of an array**.

### Get rid of the array

First, we remove the `coords` declaration and replace it with a `prevCoord`.
Without adding initialization, it'll stay at `undefined` for the first round.
We're fine with that.

```
// old
var coords = [];

// new
var prevCoord;
```

### Slightly different condition

We do not need to compute the `max` anymore -- the original code uses it to grab the "current" and "previous" coordinate, but we're moving away from that.
Also, the condition is now different.
We just need to ask if `prevCoord` is undefined.

```
// old
var max = coords.length - 1;
if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {

// new
if (typeof prevCoord !== "undefined") {
```

### Simplify the contents of `if`

Let's see what happens inside.
Before we incorporate our change, let's notice that in your first line within `if`, you've got an expression `coords[max]`.
That's actually the element you've just `push`'d, right?
So we can replace `coords[max]` with just `coord` (the current coordinate).

Then, we also not need the `prev = coords[max - 1]` part because we already have the previous coordinate stored in `prevCoord`.

In other words, that line's a goner because we have the refs we need at hand.

```
// old
var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];

// new
// not needed: curr is coord and prev is prevCoord
```

Now, the drawing commands become the following:

```
// old
context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);

// new
context.moveTo(prevCoord.x, prevCoord.y);
context.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
```

### Store the current as previous

Now, the main part.

The idea is not that far from what you have here.
Instead of pushing into array, you can just overwrite the `prevCoord`:

```
prevCoord = coord
```

Of course, you cannot do it as soon as you grab the `coord` from the `event` and `offset` stuff -- you need the `prevCoord` to draw the line.
So, just overwrite it **after drawing**.

```
// old
coords.push(coord);
if (typeof prevCoord !== "undefined") {
    // ...
}

// new
if (typeof prevCoord !== "undefined") {
    // ...
}
prevCoord = coord;
```

See -- just after using the `prevCoord` to draw a line between previous and current, we don't need the `prevCoord` anymore.
We can use this variable to prepare for the next cycle: on next mouse move, the "current" will become "previous"... meaning that when we run this function the next time, `prevCoord` will be just what it needs to be: the coordinate that was "mouse overed" the *previous* time.

### Polish up

There's one more place let to change: the `click` handler.
Just as you reset your array, you should reset the `prevCoord` back to `undefined`.

```
// old
coords = [];

// new
prevCoord = undefined;
```

### Full code

Here's the complete deal.

```js
var draw = false;
var prevCoord;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    prevCoord = undefined
    draw = !draw;
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (draw) {
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var coord = { 'x': event.x - this.offsetLeft, 'y': event.y - this.offsetTop };
        if (typeof prevCoord !== "undefined") {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(prevCoord.x, prevCoord.y);
            context.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
            context.stroke();
        }
        prevCoord = coord
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid red"></canvas>
```

## More suggestions

A couple of things...

### Redefining `context`

You have, on your fourth line, in the global scope a `var context = ...`, and then inside the `if (draw)` you have a `context = ...`. 
There's no need to run that each time.
The `context` doesn't change.

```
// old
if (draw) {
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// new
if (draw)
```

### Check for `undefined`

You don't need to use `typeof x != 'undefined'` here.
It's used when you're not sure if `x` has been *declared*.
A simple check would do.

```
// old
if (typeof prevCoord !== "undefined") {

// new
if (prevCoord !== undefined) {
```

---

That's all!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. To be honest, I didn't notice much performance improvement, but I always have this nagging voice asking "could this be done better?".

Also, I'm still unsure what you're trying to say in the 'Check for `undefined`' section. Is one `if` statements, performance-wise, better?

Comment: The `typeof` way is useful when you're afraid that accessing something could **throw**, without caring if the value is `undefined` or not. It's usually used by frameworks when testing for presence of a library or environment. For example, a plugin could ask `typeof window != 'undefined'` to check if it's executed in browser or `typeof $ != 'undefined'` to check if you're using jQuery. If they used `$ != null`, it'd break the script if you're not using jQuery. In your example, you know your code (you've got `var prevCoord`), so it's weird to use that pattern.

Comment: You wouldn't see any performance issues with your old approach, by the way. It's more about memory. With a very large canvas and a very persistent user, after some hours you could start accumulating gigabytes which would use up all RAM. It's more of a theoretical than practical problem, to be fair. That said, if you were storing more stuff, it _might_ turn into an issue sooner than expected. It's worth knowing the prev/curr trick with swapping variables -- it's a common one.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined")` loop, adding the following two lines will ensure that only two pairs of coordinates are kept inside `coords` when drawing

```
if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {
    var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
    context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
    context.stroke();
    coords = [];
    coords.push(curr);
}
```

The reason it's necessary to add `curr` into the array is because on the next mouse move `curr` will be `prev` and therefore the line will be continuous. Adding just the line

```
if (typeof coords[max - 1] !== "undefined") {
    var curr = coords[max], prev = coords[max - 1];
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
    context.lineTo(curr.x, curr.y);
    context.stroke();
    coords = [];
}
```

Would cause the drawn line to appear spotty, as after a line is drawn, it will only draw again after *two* more mouse moves.

*Note: this is the first time I've answered my own question, so please let me know if there are aspects of the answer I could improve upon*